# Get readable access to CSSMediaRule

Tags: javascript, css

I've read on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSMediaRule

```
interface CSSMediaRule : CSSConditionRule {
    readonly attribute MediaList media;
}
```

So, when css-file is outside page's domain, js code cannot access the cssrules: `securityerror` is thrown.

Is it possible to get the cssrules only in a variable in a kind of "readonly mode"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see by the error, being able to access cross domain CSS is prevented as a security measure. You'll find that any cross domain active content is treated this way, including other included javascript and iframe content.

However, as this is a browser feature, it would be possible to have the server intervene to work around this restriction. If you were able to serve the CSS from the same domain (for example, by having the server fetch the third-party CSS and then presenting it to the page as its own) then you wouldn't be constrained by cross domain issues. Keep in mind that this would be bypassing a security feature and therefor increasing potential risk.